# Сложить все переданные аргументы функции

Tags: javascript

Допустим, встала задача сложить все переданные аргументы функции.

Вот код:

```js
function sum(...rest) {
    let res;
    for (let num of rest) {
        res += num;
    }
    return res;
}

alert(sum(1, 5, 23, 2, 0, 9, 9));
```

Вопрос: почему вместо суммы всех чисел выводится `NaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

начальное значение `res` не установлено и по умолчанию оно равно `undefined`.

При сложении `undefined` с числом - результат будет `NaN`, при дальнейшем сложении `NaN` с числами результат так же остается `NaN`.

Для решения достаточно инициализировать `res`, например `0`

```js
function sum(...rest) {
  let res = 0;
  for (let num of rest) {
    res += num;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(sum(1, 5, 23, 2, 0, 9, 9));
```